# remove url link found inUItextview when a url is typed in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am usin a text view. I want remove if a url is typed inside the text view.I am not able to do that after finding the url present.can any one please help

Comment: can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool

Delegate method you have to check substring of TextView text is url u have to remove substring and apply text to UITextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i think this will help you.

```
 let texty : String = "http://www.google.com. I am vaishanvi, Competed Bachelor degree (Information technology). My blog url is http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.in, Check It"
        let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link
        var URLStrings = [NSURL]()
        let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
        let matches = detector!.matches(in: texty, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, texty.characters.count))
        textView.text = texty
        for match in matches {
            URLStrings.append(match.url! as NSURL)
            let path:String = match.url!.absoluteString
            textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: path, with:"")
        }
        print(textView.text)
        print(URLStrings)
```